# Why does C# SqlConnection.StateChange event NOT get fired in real time when SQL Server database is not available?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I have code here where the connection does connect, but I keep looping to get to know if the connection is no longer available (i.e. if a SQL Server database is no longer available).

I open a connection and subscribe to the `StateChange` event of the connection.

If within 60 seconds (time of the transaction), I manually take the SQL Server database offline or stop the SQL Server service, even then the connection state changed event is not called.

So how does one get to know in real time if the SQL Server database or SQL Server Service is unavailable, or the connection has been lost?

NOTE: I run this script on SQL Server SSMS within 60 seconds to take the database offline.

```
USE master
GO

ALTER DATABASE [databaseName]
SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO
```

This is the code in C#:

```
private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var options = new TransactionOptions()
        {
            IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead,
            Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)
        };

    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, options))
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Connection String"))
        {
            con.Open();
            con.StateChange += new StateChangeEventHandler(OnConnectionStateChanged);

            while (true)
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
            }
        }
    }
}

private void OnConnectionStateChanged(object sender, StateChangeEventArgs args)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Connection state was changed.");
}
```

If I am looping and waiting, even if the SQL Server database is taken offline, I am not notified by `SqlConnection.StateChange`.

NOTE: The continuous while loop is just to emulate any processes in the transaction, to check if connection state gets fired or not.

Comment: This seems like a futile attempt to **ensure** that a connection is still alive - and while this may be true the nanosecond you check for it, 10 nanoseconds later, it might be gone. So really this checking is pointless and moot - what you **really** need to do is write your SQL querying code in such a way that you **anticipate** that there might be a service interruption or a connection lost - and be prepared to handle such a case. Put your effort into proper and useful **exception handling** instead of trying to ensure something you really cannot guarantee anyways...

Comment: I just want to throw a custom exception if the connection is lost. The continuous loop is just to emulate any processes in the transaction, to check if connection state gets fired or not. Should not the state of connection change to Broken or Closed if the database or sqlserver instance is no longer available. After all the connection is to the database of the sqlserver.

Answer (score 1):

`StateChange` event will never get fired because is meant for the state of the connection, not for the instance of the database, so it wouldn't work as a health check to see if your database is up.

[From the docs:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbconnection.statechange?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1)

> The StateChange event occurs when the state of the connection changes from closed to opened or from opened to closed.

I'm not aware of the architecture of this application, but maybe a [Database Probe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-3.1#database-probe) could help you here.

Alternatively, you could run something like this:

```
private static bool IsServerConnected(string connectionString)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            return true; 
        }
        catch (SqlException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Where you could throw a custom exception instead of returning false if that is what you need.

Hope this helps!

Comment: But should not the state of connection change to Broken or Closed if the database or sqlserver instance is no longer available. After all the connection is to the database of the sqlserver.